# Formatting Razor files in Visual Studio with Prettier styling

Tags: visual-studio, razor, blazor

Is there an Visual Studio extension or Rosyln analyser that will help me format the markup in Razor files to be more like the markup that Prettier produces for JSX/TSX?

For example, let assume I have the following Razor code.

```html
<MudTableSortLabel InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending" SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x => x.Date)">Date</MudTableSortLabel>
```

I would like it to produce something like this.

```html
<MudTableSortLabel
    InitialDirection="SortDirection.Ascending"
    SortBy="new Func<WeatherForecast, object>(x => x.Date)"
>
    Date
</MudTableSortLabel>
```

Comment: have you figured this out? I would like to do the same

Comment: @CameronFitzpatrick sorry, haven't figured it out yet